# EF One child for multiply parrents

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, relationship

I have EF6 Code First model design like this. What is the best way to know who is a Parent (`ParentA` or `ParentB`) from `Another` class.Thank you!

```
public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Another> AnotherList { get; set; }
}

public class Another
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public Child Child { get; set; }
    public string AnotherName { get; set; }
}

public class ParentA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public Child Child { get; set; }
}

public class ParentB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public Child Child { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ParentA> ParentA { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ParentB> ParentB { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Child> Child { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Another> Another { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `Child` needs a `ParentA` and a `ParentB` property, turning this into two 1:1 associations. I The alternative is called polymorphic associations, but I wouldn't do that if it isn't absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In the setup described above, EF will put one-to-many relationships between parent and children. However, in case the same child can be referenced by ParentA and ParentB, you might want to have it configured as many-to-many. You can find how to do it in the EF documentation: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Regarding the question of how to find out who references the child, you can formulate a simple query such as:

```
context.ParentAs.Where(p => p.ChildId == id).Any()
```

This will tell you whether there is a ParentA which references your child.

If you want to have it more elegant, you could relate the two parents with each other:

```
class Parent{ /* ... */ }
class ParentA : Parent{ /* ... */ }
class ParentB : Parent { /* ... */ }
```

And then reference the Parent from the Child rather than the other way around:

```
class Child
{
    public Parent Parent{ get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Roland. The problem is that ParentA and ParentB already inherited from another classes for example ParentA: Class1, ParentB: Class2.

Comment: OK. Then you can still use a sub query, but it will be difficult to have a corresponding property in your domain model....